# Not able to ssh in to remote machine using shell script in Crontab

Tags: shell, ssh, cron, authentication

Below is the script which i am trying to run, which runs without any issue

```
for i in `seq 200 2100`
do
  usr=(`ssh -t -t -o ConnectTimeout=60 machine$1 finger | tail -1 | awk '{print$1}'`) 
  echo $usr
done
```

But once I add it to crontab, it doesn't give me the user.

```
22  12  *  *  *  sh /home/subrahmanyam/Scripts/who.sh
```

Please give your thoughts.....

may be cron demon is running, so we need to include some binaries...?

Comment: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

Comment: What are your intenesions with this? What are you trying to achieve. Just so you know we cant assist on any malicious activity if that is your intension

Answer (score 16):

You can make ssh connections within a cron session. What you need is to setup a public key authentication to have passwordless access. For this to work, you need to have `PubkeyAuthentication yes` in each remote server's `sshd_config`.

You can create a private/public key pair with or without a passphrase. If you use a passphrase (recommented) you need to also start ssh-agent. Without a passphrase, you only need to add the parameter `-i your_identity_file` to `ssh` command line. `ssh` will use `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` as default.

I replicated your example by using a key pair with a passphrase. Here's how I did it.

1) Created the key pair with passphrase. Saved the private key as `~/.ssh/id_rsa_test`, which should have the correct permissions by default. We can enter an empty passphrase for not using one.

```
john@coffee:~$ ssh-keygen -N "somephrase" -f .ssh/id_rsa_test
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in .ssh/id_rsa_test.
Your public key has been saved in .ssh/id_rsa_test.pub.
[snip]
```

2) Sent the public key to the servers, did the same for all of them. Remember they need to have `PubkeyAuthentication` enabled.

```
john@coffee:~$ ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa_test server1
The authenticity of host 'server1 (11.22.33.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 79:e8:0d:f5:a3:33:1c:ae:f5:24:55:86:82:31:b2:76.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'server1,11.22.33.1' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
john@server1's password: 
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'server1'", and check in:

  .ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.
```

3) Run ssh-agent as service with `-s`. This will not kill it if you logout. Its output is a valid shell script, setting the environment so ssh client will know how to connect to it. We save that to a file (only the first line is really needed).

```
john@coffee:~$ ssh-agent -s | head -n 1 > ssh-agent.cf 
john@coffee:~$ cat ssh-agent.cf 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-VhyKL22691/agent.22691; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
```

4) Loaded the above to our current environment so we can use `ssh-add` to add our private key to `ssh-agent`.  the passphrase from above.

```
john@coffee:~$ source ssh-agent.cf 
john@coffee:~$ ssh-add  .ssh/id_rsa_test
Enter passphrase for .ssh/id_rsa_test: 
Identity added: .ssh/id_rsa_test (.ssh/id_rsa_test)
```

5) Verified it is added.

```
john@coffee:~$ ssh-add -l
2048 96:58:94:67:da:67:c0:5f:b9:0c:40:9b:52:62:55:6a .ssh/id_rsa_test (RSA)
```

6) The script I used, slightly modified than yours. Notice that I did not enclose the ssh command in parentheses and not using backticks rather `$()`, which is a better alternative for command substitution (this is `bash` compatible, you didn't mention which shell you're using). I used the exact same ssh command as yours.

```
john@coffee:~$ cat foo.sh 
#!/bin/bash

source /home/john/ssh-agent.cf
for server in server1 server2; do
    usr=$(ssh -t -t -o ConnectTimeout=60 $server finger | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}')
    date=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=60 $server date)
    echo "$server - $date - $usr" >> /home/john/foo.log
done
```

7) My crontab (note that my `sh` is actually `bash`)

```
john@coffee:~$ crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1  *  *  *  *  sh /home/john/foo.sh
```

8) The output

```
john@coffee:~$ tail -n 4 foo.log
server1 - Wed Mar 23 14:12:03 EET 2011 - john
server2 - Wed Mar 23 14:12:04 EET 2011 - john
server1 - Wed Mar 23 14:13:03 EET 2011 - john
server2 - Wed Mar 23 14:13:04 EET 2011 - john
```

The only problem with using a passphrase is that you need to enter it manually at least one time. So, the above will not automatically work after a reboot.

Comment: Wonderful - thanks.  I can live with the no automatic restart after reboot for now, at least.

Comment: Use ssh-cron to set up scheduled SSH connections to secure servers without exposing your SSH keys, but using SSH agent. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8903/not-able-to-ssh-in-to-remote-machine-using-shell-script-in-crontab/300093#300093

Answer (score 4):

Who types the password?  The cron job can't get at your ssh-agent, so public key won't work.

You need to supply `ssh` with a key file explicitly (see the `-i` option), since it can't query an agent; and that key *must* have an empty passphrase.

Comment: Tried by passing the username and password too --  ssh -t -t -o ConnectTimeout=60 user@machine$1 finger | tail -1 | awk '{print$1}' < /home/user/passwd ---- i mean home directory is on NFS, so it mounts to everymachine

Comment: If ssh has any sense, it's using `/dev/tty` to read the password instead of `stdin`; that won't work from cron.

Comment: Tried giving -i option but no luck!  ---- ssh -o ConnectTimeout=60 -i /home/subrahmanyam/.ssh/known_hosts machine$1 finger | tail -1 | awk '{print$1}'------WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!
Permissions 0640 for '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key:

Comment: Why is it complaining about `known_hosts`?  But yes, you need to watch out for permissions — the private key file should be mode 0600 or even 0400, owned by you.  If you need some other user to be able to use it as well, you'll have look into POSIX ACLs or similar.

Comment: Come to think of it, I saw GSSAPI being offered in there so another possibility is to get a keytab and use it to `kinit` inside the cron job.  That said, keytabs also require the same care in permissions; but `ssh` at least won't complain about them.

Comment: got the permissions fixed!...but -i option is for the identity, but i have got only known_hosts under .ssh subrahmanyam@bond:~/.ssh$ ls -l
total 732
-rw------- 1 subrahmanyam nonconf 741430 Mar  9 12:58 known_hosts
subrahmanyam@bond:~/.ssh$  --- how can i generate identity cert so that i can try out even option -i. Thanks for your help in debugging!

Comment: `ssh-keygen` generates personal and host keys.  Passphrase-protected ssh keys are a good idea, in general --- but if your university uses AFS, you won't be able to use ssh key auth (the system has no way to get a token for you, so you won't be able to access your home directory).

Comment: Use ssh-cron to set up scheduled SSH connections to secure servers without exposing your SSH keys, but using SSH agent. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8903/not-able-to-ssh-in-to-remote-machine-using-shell-script-in-crontab/300093#300093

Answer (score 1):

Rather than store a temporary file like forcefsck did, I prefer to use `find` to search for on active agent.

At the topic of a script that needs the `ssh-agent`, I use:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(find /run/user/$(id -u)/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -path '*keyring-*' -name 'ssh' -print -quit 2>/dev/null)
```

It searches for the `ssh-agent` socket and returns the first one. It is restricted to only the current user, therefore you won't accidentally try to use another users and get a permission denied error.  You would also need to already be logged in with an active `ssh-agent`. (Ubuntu starts an agent when the GUI starts up).

If you put this in another script, you'll need to call it with `source` or `.` because it needs to set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ssh-cron](https://github.com/fbb-git/ssh-cron) to set up scheduled SSH connections to secure servers without exposing your SSH keys, but using SSH agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your script or command in crontab like:

```
0 * * * * bash -c -l "/home/user/sshscript.sh"
```

or

```
0 * * * * bash -c -l "ssh root@yourhost 'echo $HOSTNAME'"
```