# Running Unison with incrond (inotify cron daemon)

Tags: centos, inotify, unison

We'd like to use `unison` to sync two servers. From the command line and in bash files the following command works fine:

```
unison -batch /var/www/html/test ssh://host-2//var/www/html/test
```

Files are being synchronized and `unison.log` is being updated. so far so good.

in combination with a preference file, such as `.unison/default.prf` and simply executing `unison` from the command line as described [here](https://snapdev.net/2015/07/31/install-run-sync-unison-on-centos-7/), things work fine too.

We've also installed `incrond` inotify cron daemon and it's running smooth. The following cron job is being executes just fine:

```
/var/www/html/test IN_MODIFY,IN_ATTRIB,IN_CREATE touch /root/test
```

`/root/test` is being updated every time I make changes to files in `/var/www/html/test`

So far so good! But the only things that don't work using the incrontab are:

```
/var/www/html/test IN_MODIFY,IN_ATTRIB,IN_CREATE unison

/var/www/html/test IN_MODIFY,IN_ATTRIB,IN_CREATE /usr/bin/unison

/var/www/html/test IN_MODIFY,IN_ATTRIB,IN_CREATE /usr/local/sbin/unison

/var/www/html/test IN_MODIFY,IN_ATTRIB,IN_CREATE unison -batch /var/www/html/test ssh://host-2//var/www/html/test

/var/www/html/test IN_MODIFY,IN_ATTRIB,IN_CREATE /usr/bin/unison -batch /var/www/html/test ssh://host-2//var/www/html/test

/var/www/html/test IN_MODIFY,IN_ATTRIB,IN_CREATE /usr/local/sbin/unison -batch /var/www/html/test ssh://host-2//var/www/html/test'
```

Nothing shows in the `unison.log` file, let alone updating the remote server.The following also doesn't output anything.

```
/var/www/html/test IN_MODIFY,IN_ATTRIB,IN_CREATE unison &> /root/test.log
```

`/root/test.log` is not even being created.

Another test using a batch file named `sync.sh` also doesn't work.

in the incrontab:

```
/var/www/html/test IN_MODIFY,IN_ATTRIB,IN_CREATE /root/sync.sh
```

and in `sync.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /root/test
/usr/bin/unison -batch /var/www/html/test ssh://host-2//var/www/html/test
```

Again, `/root/test` is being touched just fine, meaning inofify works great every time I update a file in `/var/www/html/test`, but again no result at all from `unison`.

/var/log/cron looks like this:

```
May 21 06:33:44 Host-1 incrond[28339]: (root) CMD (sh /root/sync.sh)
```

and the `unison.log` is not being updated at all.

**Conclusions:**

1. `inotify` works fine, detects every change in the file system and executes a task, except for any `unison` task.
2. `unison` works fine from command line and in batch, except when called by the `incrond` daemon.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Some background from a working installation: `unison.log` only gets updated if files were actually synchronized. Nothing gets logged if the check determines that there were no changes that needed synchronization, or if the check fails altogether, for whatever reason. Other information gets written to stdout/stderr, but does not end up in the log file by default unless you explicitly redirect it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to establish an SSH connection, the client needs to authenticate to the server. You're probably using key-based authentication, with a key stored in a password-protected file and loaded into the SSH agent. The SSH client knows how to find the agent through the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. In a cron or incron job, the environment is not the same as in your interactive session, it's a pretty minimal one, without `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, so the SSH client can't connect to the remote machine.

If the SSH connection can't be established, Unison doesn't even start looking for files to synchronize and nothing gets written to `unison.log`.

There are error messages on the script's standard error, but you aren't logging them anywhere. Add something like `exec 2>&1 >>~/.unison-sync.log; date` to the beginning of your script.

To get the SSH connection to work, you'll either need to arrange for the Unison job to have access to your agent, or to set up a passwordless key. If you want to go through your agent, see [Not able to ssh in to remote machine using shell script in Crontab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8903/not-able-to-ssh-in-to-remote-machine-using-shell-script-in-crontab); but then it'll only work while you're logged in. If you want the synchronization to work all the time, a passwordless key is the only solution. Since you're running Unison and thus SSH as root, the private key need to be in `/root/.ssh`, not on your account. The same goes for any relevant option in `.ssh/config`. On the server side, you can authorize the public key only to run a specific unison command with a `command=…` directive in `.ssh/authorized_keys` (see [Creating a UNIX account which only executes one command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3556/creating-a-unix-account-which-only-executes-one-command/3559#3559) for an example). With a command restriction, if someone gains access to the local root account, they'll only be able to run that specific `unison …` command on `host-2`; I don't know whether Unison can be tricked into executing arbitrary code that way.